# Is there an IN operator for Power Automate Odata List Rows - Filter Rows expression

Tags: odata, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform, dataverse

What is the syntax of a Filter Expression for the DataVerse List Rows component, using a comparison similar to the SQL IN Statement.

I have tried things such as

```
name in ('name1','name2')
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function `Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.In(PropertyName='name',PropertyValues=['name1','name2'])`.

E.g. when you need to select accounts by accountnumber, the query would look like this:

```
/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=accountnumber,name&$filter=Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.In(PropertyName='accountnumber',PropertyValues=['12345888','004567763','91313313'])
```

FetchXml operators not natively supported in oData are modeled as query functions structured like this: `Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OperatorName(PropertyName='logicalname', PropertyValues=[value1, value2, ...])`.

So these options are also available:

```
$filter=Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.NotIn()
$filter=Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.Between()
```

> **Note:** query filter function names are case sensitive!

The complete list can be found on [MS Docs - Web API Query Function Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/queryfunctions?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9).